# issue while switching between views (inflated fragments) in FrameLayout

Tags: android, fragment, android-framelayout

My problem is as follows:

I have an application that has one main activity, in which there 
is a frameLayout container (containerViewId) that I use to display/inflate different fragments upon menu navigator selection.

What I actually do is that upon the activity onCreate() I create all fragments objects and add it to the frameLayout:

Pseudo code:

// in main activity
    onCreate()

```
Fragment1 fragment_1 = new Fragment1();

Fragment2 fragment_2 = new Fragment2()

Fragment3 fragment_3 = new Fragment3()

fragmentTransaction.add(containerViewId, fragment_1, "frag_1");
fragmentTransaction.add(containerViewId, fragment_2, "frag_2");
fragmentTransaction.add(containerViewId, fragment_3, "frag_3");

// hide fragments 2&3, so only fragment_1 is showed

fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment_2);

fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment_3);

.commit()..
```

Now, when the user selects specific option from the navigation view I just
hide the current fragment displayed, and show the one that is required as follows (e.g switching from fragment_1 to fragment_2):

```
 fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment_1);

 fragmentTransaction.show(fragment_2);

 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Everything works as expected (fragments are being switched successfully), but I sometimes observed that after some time (while I bring my app to front from background) previous fragments are suddenly displayed/overlapped together (even that I always hide the current fragment and show the next)

Am I missing something?
Why does it suddenly display my previous views?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace instead of stack the fragment. If you want to have the possibility to navigate back to the previous fragment, use [addToBackStack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String))

```
// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

There are methods on the fragmentmanager to get or pop the previous fragments from the backstack: popBackStack(), getBackStackEntryAt(int index) and more.

**UPDATE**

The method popBackStack pops the top of the backstack. The backstack contains [BackStackEntries](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.BackStackEntry.html). A Backstack Entry contains only some reference fields of your fragment. You should keep the fragments as variables in the containing class so that you can replace them. Note that you should always implement proper lifecycle management, for in Android you are never sure data is still in memory if you have it in the background.

Here's some information about the activity life cycle, but for fragments it's mostly the same:

> When your activity is recreated after it was previously destroyed, you
>   can recover your saved state from the Bundle that the system passes
>   your activity. Both the onCreate() and onRestoreInstanceState()
>   callback methods receive the same Bundle that contains the instance
>   state information.
>
> Because the onCreate() method is called whether the system is creating
>   a new instance of your activity or recreating a previous one, you must
>   check whether the state Bundle is null before you attempt to read it.
>   If it is null, then the system is creating a new instance of the
>   activity, instead of restoring a previous one that was destroyed.

Some official documentation about the life cycle of fragments: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

Comment: Thanks. Let's say that in the first time I replace fragment_1 and add it to backstack, now the user makes some changes on its related view, then user decide to switch to fragment_2 and i replace it as i did before and add it to backstack as well. At this point if I would like to navigate back to fragment_1,what should i do? use the getBackStackEntryAt(frag1_idx) to get the fragment reference and replace it? will it display fragment_1 view as it was leaved? with all user view changes?

Answer (score 0):

Keep it Simple. Do something like this -

```
    Fragment1 fragment_1 = new Fragment1();
    Fragment2 fragment_2 = new Fragment2();
    Fragment3 fragment_3 = new Fragment3();

    fragmentTransaction.replace(containerViewId, fragment_1, "frag_1"); //when you want show fragment 1
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

//similarly just replace with fragment2 and fragment 3 when you want to show them respectively.The trick is to replace (which internally removes all previously added fragments before adding the current fragment, thus no overlapping issues)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I can't just replace it as I need my latest fragment data to be restored when user navigates back.

Comment: This is something i think either wan't mentioned in the question or I missed it. Either ways, the solution would be to add the line `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);`   (Something which is touched upon already by another answer on the thread too)